# Swift avoid AVAudioPlayer from webview streaming

Tags: ios, swift, embed, avaudioplayer

I'm facing a issue with audio player when I clicked play in embed player.

One Kind of embed player not show the native audio player and another does.

[embed player issue video](https://www.veed.io/view/27be56c7-e1a1-4d79-9818-0b1b8a0d12cd?panel=share)

I have tried intercepting the transaction view or finding the player in subviews to remove it or add an image, but I have been unsuccessful.

I have also tried getting some event from the webView, but I haven't found anything useful.

Does anyone know how I can prevent this player from showing and only use the embedded player?

Thanks folks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simpler than I thought...

Just add the option allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true in your WKWebViewConfiguration

like this:

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
```

With this, all HTML5 media doesn't play in fullscreen, just in line.